# Getting CSS values and variables in an external JS file?

Tags: jquery

How come a code like this

```
var h = $('#searchcontainer').height();
$('#completeholder').css('height', h + 'px');
```

Works when inside the HTML file itself and not when I load it from a .js file? I tried defining a global *var h;* inside my main file hoping that the code inside the JS file would work without any luck. Any ideas? Thanks :)

Edit:
[This one does not work](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/debug/doesnotwork.html)

[This one works](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/debug/works.html)

See the comment at the top of the code :)
When you press next on the working page, the css resizes in the end, and that's because I imported the js file into the main header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that it has to do with the timing of when it is run.  If it is run before the page is loaded, then the objects will not yet be in the page and will not be found.

To make the function work no matter where it is located, put it inside a `$(document).ready()` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var h = $('#searchcontainer').height();
    $('#completeholder').css('height', h + 'px');
});
```

If what you're really trying to do is share global variables between different `$(document).ready(function()` invocations, then you need to declare the global variables outside of `$(document).ready(function()`:

```
var myGlobal;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var myGlobal = $('#searchcontainer').height();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#completeholder').css('height', myGlobal + 'px');
});
```

Globals like this are generally not a good idea in the first place, so what you really ought to do is look for a way to solve this without global variables (like passing parameters to a function call).

Some observations from seeing the actual working and non-working code:

1. You have multiple objects with the same id (like `contentholder`).  Referencing those objects by id will not work reliably and is prohibited in HTML.
2. In the inline version, you are setting the height of completeholder in the `case 'NextQuestion1':` block and in `case 'NextQuestion2Dance':`, but you are not doing that in the external JS version.  That code appears to be what fixes it.  On my browser the height gets set to 479 (the correct height) in those case statements.  That does not happen in the external JS version so the code is not identical between the two versions.

Comment: Next guess.  Is jQuery loaded before your external JS file?  JS files must be loaded in an appropriate order.  I hope you realize now that you haven't disclosed enough info for us to know what the problem is so we're just guessing.  Giving us a link to the non-working page would likely clear things up.

Comment: I actually think that the variables aren't being crossed over between the files because when take the whole code from the JS file and put it inside the html - everything works. And some of the content loads dynamically after which I insert this code also; and again it only works if I do it from within the html file.

Comment: Do you see any javascript errors in the error console or debug console?

Comment: Each `$(document).ready()` is it's own function context and you can't freely reference variables from one context to another (they are essentially local variables inside that anonymous function).  If you are trying to have global variables that you can share, then declare the global variables outside of the `$(document).ready()` so they are truly global.

Comment: I'm having trouble defining a global variable outside the document ready without breaking my search form for some reason - I'll try to clean up my code and upload everything

Comment: Why not stop using a global for a height?  Just retrieve the value whenever you need it.

Comment: Finally done :) See my edited post - sorry it took so long, I tried making my code readable in time :)

Comment: It appears to me that the code for the external JS version is missing a height assignment for the completeholder.  See point 2 that I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thanks so much for your time jfriend00 :)))) You made my day, really!